# Shorter Way for URLs with vscode on react native

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, filepath

So I have a react native project, and in that project many of my urls start looking like this: 
`import  Component from '../../component/file';`
So after this problem I saw this video by fireshipio with says I can shorten it by adding a jscofig.json file but it did not work when I wrote  `import  Component from '../../component/file';`
it just told me it could not find the path please tell me what I am supposed to do to make this working because if its possible my links will become so much shorter and smarter. Remember the programming rule do not repeat yourself so please help me follow that.
link to fireshipio vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpgZKBtW_t8

Answer (score 1):

You should Modify/Add your desired common path in `babel.config.js` file and then you can easily import any file/class without adding long paths

Here is an example of `babel.config.js` from one of my project.

```
module.exports = api => {
  api.cache(true);

  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: ['./src'],
          alias: {
            '@routes': ['./src/routes.js'],
            '@navigations': ['./src/navigations'],
            '@components': ['./src/components'], 
            '@store': ['./src/store'],
            '@images': ['./src/images'], //You can add your source path like this
            '@utils': ['./src/utils'],
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

After adding the source path in `babel.config.js` you can import the files like this in your class.

```
import SampleImage from '@images/sampleImage.png'
```

You can import like this in your any class, No need to do `'../../src/image/sampleImage.png'`

Comment: thansk man.  Sorry for the late reply will try and get back to you

Comment: Man I am realy sorry man but the solution doesnt work it just breaks my app dont know why thinking I will just do it the old fashion way.